# ConTeXt: Change "and" to "och" for two authors in bibliography

Tags: context

I want to print the Swedish word "och" instead of the English "and" in the bibliography in case of two authors. Example:

```
\mainlanguage[sv]

\startbuffer[ref]
@book {grauertlieb,
    AUTHOR = {Grauert, Hans and Lieb, Ingo},
     TITLE = {Differential- und {I}ntegralrechnung. {I}},
 PUBLISHER = {Springer-Verlag, Berlin-New York},
      YEAR = {1976},
}
\stopbuffer


\usebtxdataset[ref][ref.buffer]
\setupbtx[dataset=ref]
\definebtxrendering[ref][dataset=ref]

\starttext
\startTEXpage[offset=3bp]
Vi studerar \cite[grauertlieb].

\placelistofpublications[ref][method=dataset]
\stopTEXpage
\stoptext
```

The output is given below.

[image: Image showing and instead of och between authors]

> **Question**: How do I change the "and" to "och" between the authors, i.e. so that it becomes "H. Grauert och I. Lieb"?

I noticed that if I change `\mainlanguage[sv]` to `\mainlanguage[de]` I got "und". Thus, I suspect that this could be fixed by adding the correct translation in some file. I had a look in the file `lang-txt.lua`, and found a field "btx"->"and"->"labels", and added a row `["sv"]="och",` (there was a german `["de"]="und",`, so this could perhaps be the right place). Still, even after running `context --make`, the result from my example file was the same, with an "and" between the authors.

Another, perhaps naive try, was to try

```
\setuplabeltext[sv][and=och]
```

and

```
\setupbtxlabeltext[sv][and=och]
```

but, again, nothing changed.

For the moment I'm fine with a fix that can be applied in my tex-file, but for the future I would also be happy to have a solution that could make this work automatically for other users (i.e the correct place to add these and send a suggestion to Hans).

Comment: The label texts for the default style use all `default:` as prefix for the keys and you have to use `\setupbtxlabeltext [sv] [default:and=och]` to change the text from `and` to `och`.

Comment: Oh, so I was not so far away. Thanks! Do you know what file I can edit to make a "patch" to submit? Also, if you want to turn that comment into an answer, I will accept, since this is what I was looking for.

Comment: The settings for the `default` style are in `publ-imp-default.mkvi` but you should also look into `publ-imp-apa.mkvi` and `publ-imp-aps.mkvi` and add the missing labels for them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to the comments by Wolfgang, I got a working solution by adding

```
\setupbtxlabeltext
  [sv]
  [\s!default:and=och,
   \s!default:number={nr.},
   \s!default:edition={Utgåva},
   \s!default:Editor=Redaktör, 
   \s!default:Editors=Redaktörer,
   \s!default:Volume=Band,
   \s!default:Volumes=Band,
   \s!default:others={et al.}]
```

to the `publ-imp-default.mkvi` file, and then running `context --generate`. I have sent the updated file (as well as updated `publ-imp-apa.mkvi` and `publ-imp-aps.mkvi`) to Hans.